Can a CFI give someone he's never flown with a cross-country endorsement?
61.93(c)(1) says that, for each cross country flight, "a student pilot must have a solo cross-country endorsement from the authorized instructor who conducted the training..."
In (c)(2,3), the reg says that a student pilot must have a solo cross-country endorsement "from an authorized instructor" who reviews the student's flight planning.
Looking at 61-65J, my first impression is that the baseline general cross-country endorsement has to be from the specific instructor with whom the student did the cross-country training, but specific cross-country flights from A to B can be endorsed by an instructor who simply reviews the student's planning.
Thanks

I would have hoped a CFI would chime in here, but your interpretation seems correct to me.
